# Shorter Keys with Typescript Key Remapping (Removing Prefix)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The Typescript documentation has a section for ["Key Remapping via `as`"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). Their example makes the object key longer, such as `name` becoming `getName`. This is that example:

```js
type Getters<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `get${Capitalize<string & Property>}`]: () => Type[Property]
};
```

Is it possible to go in the reverse direction, removing the prefix instead of adding it?

```js
type InputPerson = {
  getName: () => string
}

type ExpectedOutputPerson = {
  name: string
}
```

Comment: Sure, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzGARw) meet your needs?  The example isn't exactly clear about what you want to do if your input type has any non `getXXX` properties, or if those properties aren't zero-arg function, so I made some assumptions.  If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that looks great! I had a feeling it was something to do with infer, but I couldn't quite get it. This example was just because it was from the website. For my use case, it would be ideal to throw a type error if the key did not match the pattern.

Comment: A type error like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxjBZw)?  Anyway I need to go to bed now so I'll write up an answer when I wake uo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to parse string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) as well as to concatenate them.  You need to use [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to do it by saying "does this string match `"get"` concatenated with something, and if so, what is that something?"

```
type UngetKey<K extends PropertyKey> =
    K extends `get${infer P}` ? Uncapitalize<P> : K

type Test1 = UngetKey<"getTestOne">;
// type Test1 = "testOne"
```

And now you can use it to build something that undoes your `Getters<T>`, with the proviso that you need to decide what to do when you get unexpected properties:

```
type Ungetters<T extends { [K in keyof T]:
    K extends `get${string}` ? () => any : never
}> = { [K in keyof T as UngetKey<K>]:
        ReturnType<T[K]>
    };
```

The type parameter `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that all members have to have keys starting with `"get"` and they have to be zero-arg methods:

```
type Oops = Ungetters<{ getAge(): number, oops: string }>; // error
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Types of property 'oops' are incompatible.
```

And then each property of the output is the return type of the corresponding input property, using [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype):

```
type InputPerson = {
    getMyName: () => string;
    getAge: () => number;
}

type Output = Ungetters<InputPerson>;    
/* type Output = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgcwsA0hEAeFUIA9gRwAmAzlAAoBOA9pJaGiAHxQC8AUFF1NngcWQAGSYABIA3gEs4AMwiUKAX0FQA-LDgBjAIZhJwbQBtJALwgZyLAFw927UJCgAVCCWABGNhpGMMAIhEXNwB5OAg-JgBudgB6GKgHaCCPLz8CELC-O3twaHgRAkoSDCccfEJSKHEoAG1saSgAa3RqGWcAXStObl5ygShhZAk3SmkEZTUoAAoASjYWbTgQKBswgDd5dkUWVira+rgmlrbS7TJ85F8UJk7u7m4AJWQAV0o4J1ySuvamO6hFaJ2RJQACScDAz2A5HkJGoh124j+IgAsiAAHLaAC2EBss3mUBGY2i9xEAEEkLi5qwWHBnpiAEbyaKKIG5KDBSEQ4BeC7AQrFMFc6FFOFROwxABUCTZHOAXK8iPucCxOIJwFGiGJ3G0FKgtIZTK2UAlMVZjmCtDIu15-Iw1TJSFmqzpjMoABooNRLTZCYh-lEoHEcJQaJRYvEuB9IGRWlAwDQ6KAoAByL1gEjJqDaSjQaSaaiYsDaYCSemGCAAOiAA)